# getting error in node js installation when i click on npm install

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: react-autocomplete@1.8.1
npm ERR! Found: react@18.2.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   react@"^18.2.0" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer react@">=16.8.0" from @emotion/react@11.9.3
npm ERR!   node_modules/@emotion/react
npm ERR!     @emotion/react@"^11.9.3" from the root project
npm ERR!     peer @emotion/react@"^11.0.0-rc.0" from @emotion/styled@11.9.3
npm ERR!     node_modules/@emotion/styled
npm ERR!       @emotion/styled@"^11.9.3" from the root project
npm ERR!       3 more (@mui/material, @mui/styled-engine, @mui/system)
npm ERR!     3 more (@mui/material, @mui/styled-engine, @mui/system)
npm ERR!   20 more (@emotion/styled, @mui/base, @mui/icons-material, ...)
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"^0.14.7 || ^15.0.0-0 || ^16.0.0-0" from react-autocomplete@1.8.1
npm ERR! node_modules/react-autocomplete
npm ERR!   react-autocomplete@"^1.8.1" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: react@16.14.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   peer react@"^0.14.7 || ^15.0.0-0 || ^16.0.0-0" from react-autocomplete@1.8.1
npm ERR!   node_modules/react-autocomplete
npm ERR!     react-autocomplete@"^1.8.1" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR!
npm ERR! For a full report see:
npm ERR! C:\Users\dell\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-08-13T18_37_17_676Z-eresolve-report.txt

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\dell\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-08-13T18_37_17_676Z-debug-0.log [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YMunf.png)
```

need to run the command without any errors

Comment: Show your package.json

Comment: re [react-autocomplete](https://github.com/reactjs/react-autocomplete): "This repository has been archived by the owner on Jul 20, 2019. It is now read-only." Also: "Last updated 6 years go". You should find another library. Perhaps [react-autosuggest](https://github.com/moroshko/react-autosuggest).

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to downgrade the react package to a version that is compatible with react-autocomplete@1.8.1?

Most of the time it fixes the problem.

Else you can try this:

```
npm install --legacy-peer-deps react-autocomplete
```

But even if this doesn't work for you, then I'd suggest you to start from the beginning, i.e.:

```
rm -rf node_modules
npm install
```

Answer (score 0):

**-f** **stands for** forcefully install packages.

```js
npm i -f
```

Answer (score 0):

You are facing a common problem for not being able to resolve dependency issue.
It generally happens because of mismatch node versions and the module versions specified in package.json.

You can use the --legacy-peer-deps flag to ignore this error:
`npm install --legacy-peer-deps`

or you can manually check for each package and check it's version is compatible with current npm/node version.

You can use `yarn` instead of `npm`

Head over to [this link](https://weekendprojects.dev/posts/fixed-npm-err-eresolve-unable-to-resolve-dependency-tree/) for various other fixes.

Answer (score -1):

I see you're facing an issue with npm installation due to a dependency conflict involving the `react-autocomplete` package. Don't worry, I'm here to help you tackle this!

The error message indicates that the problem lies in the version requirements of React for various packages. The `react-autocomplete@1.8.1` package you're trying to install requires React versions matching `^0.14.7 || ^15.0.0-0 || ^16.0.0-0`. However, your root project and other packages need React `18.2.0`, which doesn't match this pattern.

Let's work through this step by step:

1. **Check Node.js and npm Versions**: Ensure that you're using Node.js and npm versions that are compatible with your packages. Run these commands to check your versions:

   ```bash
   node -v
   npm -v
   ```

   If you need to update, you can download the latest versions from the official Node.js and npm websites.
2. **Clear npm Cache**: Sometimes, cached package data can cause issues. Clear the npm cache by running:

   ```bash
   npm cache clean --force
   ```
3. **Update or Reinstall Packages**:
   Try updating the packages with conflicting dependencies or simply reinstalling them using:

   ```bash
   npm update
   npm install
   ```
4. **Use `--legacy-peer-deps` Flag**: As suggested in the error message, consider running the installation with the `--legacy-peer-deps` flag to help resolve some of the dependency conflicts:

   ```bash
   npm install --legacy-peer-deps
   ```
5. **Check `react-autocomplete` Version**: If possible, see if there's an updated version of the `react-autocomplete` package that's compatible with React `18.2.0`. Update the version in your `package.json` file and then run `npm install` again.
6. **Review Package Versions**: Double-check the versions you've specified in your `package.json` file. Make sure you haven't accidentally set conflicting versions.
7. **Update All Packages**: Ensure that all your packages, including those dependent on React, are up to date. Run `npm outdated` to identify available updates.
8. **Remove `node_modules` and `package-lock.json`**: If all else fails, consider removing the `node_modules` folder and the `package-lock.json` file, and then re-run `npm install`.

Remember to back up any important configuration files or data before making changes to your project's dependencies.

If you're still facing issues, it might be helpful to reach out to the maintainers of the `react-autocomplete` package for further assistance. Additionally, exploring alternative packages that are compatible with React `18.2.0` could be a viable solution.

Best of luck, and don't hesitate to ask if you need further guidance!